# ANDROID - Custom ListView with categories

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm following that tutorial:

> http://hmkcode.com/android-custom-listview-titles-icons-counter/

I have following codes:

**../layout/target_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="#F3F3F3">

     <!-- icon -->
     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/item_icon"
         android:layout_width="32dp"
         android:layout_height="32dp"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
         android:src="@drawable/ic_action_help"
         />

    <!-- title -->
    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/item_title"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_icon"
         android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/item_counter"
         android:textSize="18dp" />

        <!-- counter -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_counter"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

***../layout/group_header_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"

    android:background="#5490CC">

    <!-- title -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/blanco"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!--  divider -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#DADADC" ></View>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**/scr/.../Model.java**

```
public class Model{

    private int icon;
    private String title;
    private String counter;

    private boolean isGroupHeader = false;

    public Model(String title) {
        this(-1,title,null);
        isGroupHeader = true;
    }
    public Model(int icon, String title, String counter) {
        super();
        this.icon = icon;
        this.title = title;
        this.counter = counter;
    }
    public int getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }
    public void setIcon(int icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }
    public void setCounter(String counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }
    public boolean isGroupHeader() {
        return isGroupHeader;
    }
    public void setGroupHeader(boolean isGroupHeader) {
        this.isGroupHeader = isGroupHeader;
    }
}
```

**src/.../MyAdapter.java**

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Model> modelsArrayList;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model> modelsArrayList) {

        super(context, R.layout.target_item, modelsArrayList);

        this.context = context;
        this.modelsArrayList = modelsArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // 1. Create inflater 
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // 2. Get rowView from inflater

        View rowView = null;
        if(!modelsArrayList.get(position).isGroupHeader()){
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.target_item, parent, false);

            // 3. Get icon,title & counter views from the rowView
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon); 
            TextView titleView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            TextView counterView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_counter);

            // 4. Set the text for textView 
            imgView.setImageResource(modelsArrayList.get(position).getIcon());
            titleView.setText(modelsArrayList.get(position).getTitle());
            counterView.setText(modelsArrayList.get(position).getCounter());
        }`enter code here`
        else{
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_header_item, parent, false);
                TextView titleView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.header);
                titleView.setText(modelsArrayList.get(position).getTitle());
        }

        // 5. retrn rowView
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

**src/.../MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);

 MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, generateData());

   setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

private ArrayList<Model> generateData(){
        ArrayList<Model> models = new ArrayList<Model>();
        models.add(new Model("group1"));
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.ic_action_help,"item 1","1"));
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.ic_action_search,"item2","25"));
 return models;
    }
}
```

**My problem**

Okay, I want add one ListView because I need clic events on items.

On tutorial I can read that on MainActicity:

```
//if extending Activity
//setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//if extending Activity 2. Get ListView from activity_main.xml
//ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
```

I tried do that but not work, I don't know how I can do that.

**UPDATE**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

//.......
```

And I added activity_main.xml with ListView called R.id.list

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**ERROR**

```
06-05 09:40:43.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1217): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-05 09:40:43.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1217): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.listprueba/com.example.listprueba.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
06-05 09:40:43.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
06-05 09:40:43.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
06-05 09:40:43.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-05 09:40:43.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
06-05 09:40:43.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-05 09:40:43.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-05 09:40:43.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
06-05 09:40:43.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 09:40:43.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-05 09:40:43.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
06-05 09:40:43.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-05 09:40:43.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-05 09:40:43.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1217): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
06-05 09:40:43.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
06-05 09:40:43.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
06-05 09:40:43.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
06-05 09:40:43.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at com.example.listprueba.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
06-05 09:40:43.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
06-05 09:40:43.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-05 09:40:43.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
06-05 09:40:43.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     ... 11 more
```

**UPDATE 2**

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        // extending Activity
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // 1. pass context and data to the custom adapter
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, generateData());

        //  Get ListView from activity_main.xml
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);


        // 3. setListAdapter
        list.setAdapter(adapter); //extending Activity
        //setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

//......
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

How I can implement ListView?

**SOLUTION**

On **MainActivity.java** I added **ListView list = getListView();** instead ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

and on **activity_main.xml** I added

```
//.....
android:id="@android:id/list"
//....
```

Thanks

Comment: there must be `NullPointerException` 

put `setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);` in `OnCreate()` method od your `MainActivity`

Comment: @Prag's yeah, always give same error, look up I edited with error log

Comment: put a Listview in your XML file.. and error will gone..

Comment: Also you never call `setContentView()` for `MainActivity`. Refer to [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html).

Comment: What is in the layout of activity_main.xml?

If it's missing the listview, it won't work:     <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </ListView>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logcat says `Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'`

In your `R.layout.activity_main` you need a `ListView` with id `android.R.id.list` because your Activity is extending from `ListActivity`. And it expect an `ListView` who is not finding. So, in your `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

And then, in your `activity_main.xml` you need to have a listiview with id `android.R.id.list`

Comment: I did, not work... I add activity_main.xml, setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); and ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list); onCreate(), not work.

Comment: No, you has to do ListView lv = getListView(), check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

Comment: What is your logcat now?

Comment: If the MainActivity is what you've posted, it is wrong, is not `ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);` and is not `R.id.list` is `android.R.id.list`. Post the activity_main.xml and MainActivity as you have it right now.

Comment: UPDATE 2 on question.

Comment: Ok, you are using `ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);`, it is `ListView list = getListView();`

Comment: ohh god!! now it's working!! now only I have to add onItemClick() and perfect!! Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need ANDROID.R.id.list, which is done as the following:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
</ListView>
```

Comment: I have the same on activity_main.xml

Comment: You don't. You have         android:id="@+id/list" and not     android:id="@android:id/list"

Comment: I hope you did not forget to call setContentView after vhanging the id

Comment: No, no, no I called, I'ts so strange...sure is a silly mistake.